# Successively Training Multiple TensorFlow Models: How do I ensure the session is clear?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, computer-vision

I am looping a program that creates a model, trains the model, evaluates the model using a test set, then deletes itself (This is working towards a K-Fold Evaluation). I need to be sure that at the end of each loop, there is no prior memory of the old model/training being held out. A code sample below shows what I have done to attempt to achieve this (some pseudo-code included to aid in understanding, and save the 100's of lines of the program):

```
for heldout_dataset in os.listdir():
  # Create model
  base_model = tf.keras.applications.Xception(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False,weights='imagenet')
  # (Etc, adding layers)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

  # (Etc, loading some data that is not held out (ie, not the 'Fold'))
  train_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(....)
  val_data = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(....)
  model.fit(train_data,val_data)

  # (Etc, making predictions)

  # Clear Everything
  del train_data
  del model
  del base_model
  del val_data
  tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
```

However, when I do this, it still seems like the predictions are getting progressively better, when in reality I would expect them to remain the same. It is achieving very high accuracy (~95%), so to me this indicates it is not clearing it's memory properly and has indeed seen the images before.

My question is as follows: How can I ensure a completely new model, with no previous training at all, is  being instanced at each loop? More or less looking for something to 'nuke' all saved variables/weights/any other info. If it matters, this is being executed in CoLab.

Thanks!

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you working in?

Comment: Hi, currently using tf.__version__ 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

When you're initialising your model(s), you're providing a `weights` argument to tell TF how to initialise the weights of each new instance:

```py
tf.keras.applications.Xception(input_shape=IMG_SHAPE, include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
```

In this case, you're telling it to use the weights from a model that has already been trained on the `imagenet` dataset. If you want a model 'with no previous training at all', you can set the weights argument to `None` instead ([see the docs here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/applications/Xception)).

EDIT:
Based on your comments, this isn't what you were after.
`tf.keras.backend.clear_session()` does what you're asking but should be called at the start of each iteration.

If your data splits are being created deterministically, you could try playing with the ordering to see whether you observe the same pattern in performance, or whether the performance gets shuffled in-line with the splits.

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the answer! I dont think this is exactly what I am looking for, so I will try to be more clear. I realize that the model is initially downloading the weights, this is as intended. However, I need to make sure that, for every iteration in the for loop shown, there is nothing left in GPU memory or RAM in CoLab that could be affecting the new model, since each iteration of the for loop will be tested on data that the model was trained on 1 iteration ago. Hopefully this is more clear, I am having trouble explaining it

Comment: So essentially the question is: Does the `del model` and `clear_session()` ensure that TensorFlow completely forgets everything?